# Keyboard Keys Randomly not working

Tags: keyboard

here are my pc's specifications:

- Asus Rog GL752V
- CPU: Intel I7-7600HQ/BGA.
- HDD: 2TB
- RAM: 32GB
- Windows 10

I've been experiencing the following:

I'm typing on notepad, Netbeans 8.2 IDE, copying text whether its copying from notepad,netbeans or Google Chrome, it just seems like the CTRL,ALT,ENTER keys are not being recognized when pressed, so I have to press it several times for it to work and this shouldn't be happening.

I've had the pc for about 9 months, truthfully I've never formatted. The problem started happening about 2 weeks ago. The pc is used for software programming, nothing that could make this pc go nuts so I don't understand why this is happening, and the only thing I can think of is to replace the keyboard which I believe should not need to be changed after only 9 months ¬¬

Affected keys:

- LEFT ALT
- LEFT CTRL
- ENTER
- SPACE

They are all affected when pressed independently or in combination with other keys as well.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an external keyboard for comparison?

Comment: jum no, I don't have one at hand.